# How to evaluate $a^b - b^a = x$

Tags: logarithms

I know the values of $a$ and $b$ and I want some other form of this equation to solve it using C++ programming language without overflow, because $a$ and $b$ can reach $100$.

I was thinking about logarithm but I could not complete the idea if we take the logarithm of the two sides:

$\log (a^b - b^a)$ = $\log x$

any idea?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I did, thanks.

Comment: MathJax hint:  if you put a backslash before common functions, you get the right font and spacing.  \log x gives $\log x$ in contrast to log x giving $log x$

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless $a$ and $b$ are very close, one of these will be *much* larger than the other.  In that case if either one overflows the difference will, too, so you might as well just do the straightforward computation.  Contrast $$10^{12}=1,000,000,000,000\\12^{10}=61,917,364,224$$
Taking the difference doesn't reduce $10^{12}$ much at all.  If $a,b$ are integers just test for equality.  If they are equal return $0$, otherwise compute it as written and let it overflow.

Comment: I think the final answer should fit in long long, but the computations in between will overflow

Comment: I think the OP wants to get $\log(x)$ even if $x$ itself would overflow.  I covered that in my answer.

Comment: You have a problem with your thousands separators.

Comment: @AliOsm:  my point is that will not happen.

Comment: @ericw31415:  Thanks.  Fixed.

Comment: @CMonsour:  I didn't think so.  I think OP thinks the subtraction will bring it back into range.  Your point is a good one and I upvoted.

Comment: oh ok I got you, so there is no answer with other form, I think the only method is to use BigInteger class from Java

Answer (score 1):

Evaluate $b \log(a)$ and $a \log(b)$.  Suppose, for example, that $a \log(b)$ is smaller.  $b \log(a) - a \log(b)=\log(\frac{a^b}{b^a})$.  If this is so large that exponentiating causes overflow (or even gives you a 20-digit number), then for all practical purposes $x=a^b-b^a$ is just $a^b$ for purposes of the number of significant digits you have, and you are done (i.e., $\log(x)=b \log(a)$ to avoid overflow).  If $b \log(a) - a \log(b)$ is less than $\log(10^{20})$ or so, exponentiate it and subtract $1$ to get $\frac{x}{b^a}$.  If $b^a$ is not too large, solve directly.  If $b^a$ is very large, take the log again to get $\log(x)-a\log(b)$, and then add $a\log(b)$ to get $\log(x)$.

The key thing is to realize that is $b \log(a)$ is sufficiently larger than $a \log(b)$, then $a^b-b^a$ will just be $a^b$.  And of course (which I think you already know) to realize that if $x$ would overflow, you would still like to return $\log (x)$.

Comment: If the difference between $b\log(a)$ and $a\log(b)$ is greater than $\log (10)$ the larger is over $10$ times the smaller and the subtraction will not bring the computation into range.  It is $b \log (a)$ that should be tested for being so large that exponentiating it will cause an overflow.

Comment: Your first statement  would be true if you said greater than $10$, but as I said if exponentiating is large enough to cause overflow, then $a^b-b^a$ is functionally $a^b$ and the answer is basically $\log(x)$=$b\log(a)$.  As for the second, I said if $b^a$ is not too large...that's called testing.  I give a way to handle that case to get $\log(x)$.